# Bad magic number for Bundle with Xamarin Android AIDL parcelable

Tags: android, xamarin, parcelable, aidl

I am getting object Marshall error  while transferring parcelable objects via AIDL between Server & Client as two different Xamarin Android applications(Or with different process for Service):

```
 07-11 17:30:35.971 I/mono-stdout(23384):
 Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x610072
     Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x610072
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
       at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
 method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
 <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
       at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms)
 [0x0000e] in <9ab9faae1b4b4f0da28e7c4ac61e2c78>:0 
       at Android.OS.IParcelableCreatorInvoker.CreateFromParcel (Android.OS.Parcel source) [0x0005a] in
 <9ab9faae1b4b4f0da28e7c4ac61e2c78>:0 
       at AIDLBindingServer.IAdditionServiceStub+Proxy.GetParcelableObj () [0x0002f] in
 C:\Projects\xn\aidl\AIDLBindingLib\AIDLBindingServer\AIDLBindingServer\obj\Release\aidl\IAdditionService.cs:124

       at Xamarin.AidlDemo.Activity1.<OnStart>b__10_0 (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x000c5] in
 C:\Projects\xn\aidl\AIDLDemoClient\AIDLDemoClient\Activity1.cs:53 
       --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x610072
     07-11 17:30:35.976 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
 [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.readFromParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1443)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.<init>(BaseBundle.java:128)
        at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:69)
        at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1879)
        at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1863)
        at android.os.Bundle$1.createFromParcel(Bundle.java:1127)
        at android.os.Bundle$1.createFromParcel(Bundle.java:1126)
        at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native
 Method)
        at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:
     886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     07-11 17:30:35.976 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod
 (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
 method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
 <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
     07-11 17:30:35.976 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jobject,
 System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in
 <9ab9faae1b4b4f0da28e7c4ac61e2c78>:0 
     07-11 17:30:35.976 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at Android.OS.IParcelableCreatorInvoker.CreateFromParcel
 (Android.OS.Parcel source) [0x0005a] in
 <9ab9faae1b4b4f0da28e7c4ac61e2c78>:0 
     07-11 17:30:35.976 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at AIDLBindingServer.IAdditionServiceStub+Proxy.GetParcelableObj ()
 [0x0002f] in
 C:\Projects\xn\aidl\AIDLBindingLib\AIDLBindingServer\AIDLBindingServer\obj\Release\aidl\IAdditionService.cs:124

     07-11 17:30:35.976 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at Xamarin.AidlDemo.Activity1.<OnStart>b__10_0 (System.Object sender,
 System.EventArgs e) [0x000c5] in
 C:\Projects\xn\aidl\AIDLDemoClient\AIDLDemoClient\Activity1.cs:53 
     07-11 17:30:35.976 I/mono-stdout(23384):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x610072
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.BaseBundle.readFromParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1443)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.BaseBundle.<init>(BaseBundle.java:128)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:69)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1879)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1863)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.Bundle$1.createFromParcel(Bundle.java:1127)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.Bundle$1.createFromParcel(Bundle.java:1126)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native
 Method)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
     07-11 17:30:35.977 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     07-11 17:30:35.978 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     07-11 17:30:35.978 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     07-11 17:30:35.978 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
     07-11 17:30:35.978 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     07-11 17:30:35.978 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
     07-11 17:30:35.978 I/mono-stdout(23384):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

IAdditionService.aidl

```
package AIDLBindingServer;

interface IAdditionService {
int add(in int value1, in int value2);
ParcelableObj  getParcelableObj();
}
```

ParcelableObj.aidl

```
package AIDLBindingServer;

parcelable ParcelableObj;
```

ParcelableObj.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Java.Interop;
using Java.Lang;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;

namespace AIDLBindingServer
{
    [Register("AIDLBindingServer.ParcelableObj", DoNotGenerateAcw = false)]
    public class ParcelableObj : Object, IParcelable
    {
        /*private static readonly long serialVersionUID = -3892107077759983950L;*/
      //  static readonly int BUNDLE_MAGIC = 0x4C444E42;
        [ExportField ("CREATOR")]
        public static ParcelableObjCreator InitializeCreator()
        {
            return new ParcelableObjCreator();
        }

        public ParcelableObj()
        {
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public ParcelableObj(string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
        }

        #region IParcelable implementation
        public int DescribeContents()
        {
            return 0;

        }

        public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
        {
            dest.WriteString(this.Name);
        }
        #endregion
    }

    [Register("AIDLBindingServer.ParcelableObjCreator", DoNotGenerateAcw = false)]
    public sealed class ParcelableObjCreator : Object, IParcelableCreator
    {
        public Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
        {
            return new ParcelableObj(source.ReadString());
        }

        public Object[] NewArray(int size)
        {
             return new Java.Lang.Object[size];
           // throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

AdditionService.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Xamarin.AidlDemo
{
    [Service(Process = "com.xamarin.additionservice")]
    [IntentFilter(new String[] {"com.xamarin.additionservice"})]
    public class AdditionService: Service
    {
        private static readonly string Tag = "AdditionService";
        private AdditionServiceBinder _binder;

        public override void OnCreate ()
        {
            base.OnCreate ();
            Log.Debug (Tag, "Addition Service created.");
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind (Intent intent)
        {
            _binder = new AdditionServiceBinder();
            return _binder;
        }
        public override void OnDestroy ()
        {
            base.OnDestroy ();
            Log.Debug (Tag, "Addition service stopped.");
        }

    }
}
```

AdditionServiceBinder.cs

```
using Android.Util;
using System;
using AIDLBindingServer;

namespace Xamarin.AidlDemo
{
    public class AdditionServiceBinder: IAdditionServiceStub, IAdditionService
    {
        public static readonly string Tag = "AdditionServiceBinder";
        public override int Add (int value1, int value2)
        {
            Log.Debug (Tag, "AdditionService.Add({0}, {1})", value1, value2);
            return value1 + value2;
        }

        public override ParcelableObj GetParcelableObj()
        {
            /*throw new NotImplementedException();*/
            return new ParcelableObj("raheem"/*,"32"*/);
        }
    }
}
```

AdditionServiceConnection.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using AIDLBindingCLib;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Xamarin.AidlDemo
{
    class AdditionServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
    {
        Activity1 _activity;

        public AdditionServiceConnection (Activity1 activity)
        {
            _activity = activity;
        }

        public IAdditionService Service 
        {
            get; private set;
        }

        public void OnServiceConnected (ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            Service =   IAdditionServiceStub.AsInterface(service);
            _activity.Service = (IAdditionService) Service;
            _activity.IsBound = Service != null;

        }

        public void OnServiceDisconnected (ComponentName name)
        {
            _activity.Service = null;
            _activity.IsBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Activity1.cs

```
using System;
using AIDLBindingCLib;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Java.Interop;

namespace Xamarin.AidlDemo
{
    [Activity (Label = "AIDL Demo Server", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        public static readonly String Tag = "Activity1";
        private AdditionServiceConnection _serviceConnection;

        public IAdditionService Service { get; set; }

        public bool IsBound { get; set; }


        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            base.OnStart ();
            InitService ();

            var button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.buttonCalc);

            button1.Click += (sender, e) => {
                if (IsBound) {
                    var text1 = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.value1);
                    var text2 = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.value2);
                    var primitive_result = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.primitive_result);
                    var parcelable_result = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.parcelable_result);
                    var connection_result = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.connection_result);

                    int v1;
                    int v2;
                    int v3;


                    if(Int32.TryParse (text2.Text, out v2) && Int32.TryParse (text1.Text, out v1)) {
                        v3 = Service.Add (v1, v2);
                    } else {
                        v3 = 0;
                        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.SetMessage("Spaces or special character are not allowed");
                        builder.SetNeutralButton("OK", (source, eventArgs) => {});
                        builder.Show();
                    }
                    primitive_result.Text = v3.ToString();

                    try
                    {
                        ParcelableObj obj = Service.GetParcelableObj();
                        parcelable_result.Text= "parcelable_result:"+ obj.Name;
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(exception);
                        parcelable_result.Text = "parcelable_result:" + exception.Message;
                    }



                } else {
                    Log.Warn (Tag, "The AdditionService is not bound");
                }

            };

        }

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.main);
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy ()
        {
            base.OnDestroy ();
            ReleaseService ();
        }

        private void InitService ()
        {
            _serviceConnection = new AdditionServiceConnection (this);
            var additionServiceIntent = new Intent ("com.xamarin.additionservice");
            additionServiceIntent.SetPackage("AIDLDemo.AIDLDemo");
            bool ret = BindService (additionServiceIntent, _serviceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
            Log.Debug (Tag, "Service initialized:"+ret);
            try
            {
                var connection_result = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.connection_result);
                connection_result.Text = "Service initialized:" + ret;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);

            }

        }

        private void ReleaseService ()
        {
            if (IsBound) {
                ApplicationContext.UnbindService (_serviceConnection);
                IsBound = false;
                _serviceConnection = null;
                Log.Debug (Tag, "Service released.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generated IAdditionServiceStub

```
// This file is automatically generated and not supposed to be modified.
using System;
using Boolean = System.Boolean;
using String = System.String;
using List = Android.Runtime.JavaList;
using Map = Android.Runtime.JavaDictionary;

namespace Xamarin.AidlDemo
{
    public interface IAdditionService : global::Android.OS.IInterface
    {
        int Add (int value1, int value2);
        global::Xamarin.AidlDemo.ParcelableObj GetParcelableObj ();
    }

    public abstract class IAdditionServiceStub : global::Android.OS.Binder, global::Android.OS.IInterface, Xamarin.AidlDemo.IAdditionService
    {
        const string descriptor = "Xamarin.AidlDemo.IAdditionService";
        public IAdditionServiceStub ()
        {
            this.AttachInterface (this, descriptor);
        }

        public static Xamarin.AidlDemo.IAdditionService AsInterface (global::Android.OS.IBinder obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;
            var iin = (global::Android.OS.IInterface) obj.QueryLocalInterface (descriptor);
            if (iin != null && iin is Xamarin.AidlDemo.IAdditionService)
                return (Xamarin.AidlDemo.IAdditionService) iin;
            return new Proxy (obj);
        }

        public global::Android.OS.IBinder AsBinder ()
        {
            return this;
        }

        protected override bool OnTransact (int code, global::Android.OS.Parcel data, global::Android.OS.Parcel reply, int flags)
        {
            switch (code) {
            case global::Android.OS.BinderConsts.InterfaceTransaction:
                reply.WriteString (descriptor);
                return true;

            case TransactionAdd: {
                data.EnforceInterface (descriptor);
                int arg0 = default (int);
                arg0 = data.ReadInt ();
                int arg1 = default (int);
                arg1 = data.ReadInt ();
                var result = this.Add (arg0, arg1);
                reply.WriteNoException ();
                reply.WriteInt (result);
                return true;
                }

            case TransactionGetParcelableObj: {
                data.EnforceInterface (descriptor);
                var result = this.GetParcelableObj ();
                reply.WriteNoException ();
                if (result != null) { reply.WriteInt (1); result.WriteToParcel (reply, global::Android.OS.ParcelableWriteFlags.ReturnValue); } else reply.WriteInt (0);
                return true;
                }

            }
            return base.OnTransact (code, data, reply, flags);
        }

        public class Proxy : Java.Lang.Object, Xamarin.AidlDemo.IAdditionService
        {
            global::Android.OS.IBinder remote;

            public Proxy (global::Android.OS.IBinder remote)
            {
                this.remote = remote;
            }

            public global::Android.OS.IBinder AsBinder ()
            {
                return remote;
            }

            public string GetInterfaceDescriptor ()
            {
                return descriptor;
            }

            public int Add (int value1, int value2)
            {
                global::Android.OS.Parcel __data = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();

                global::Android.OS.Parcel __reply = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();
int __result = default (int);

                try {
                    __data.WriteInterfaceToken (descriptor);
                    __data.WriteInt (value1);
                    __data.WriteInt (value2);
                    remote.Transact (IAdditionServiceStub.TransactionAdd, __data, __reply, 0);
                    __reply.ReadException ();
                    __result = __reply.ReadInt ();

                } finally {
                    __reply.Recycle ();
                    __data.Recycle ();
                }
                return __result;

            }


            public global::Xamarin.AidlDemo.ParcelableObj GetParcelableObj ()
            {
                global::Android.OS.Parcel __data = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();

                global::Android.OS.Parcel __reply = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();
global::Xamarin.AidlDemo.ParcelableObj __result = default (global::Xamarin.AidlDemo.ParcelableObj);

                try {
                    __data.WriteInterfaceToken (descriptor);
                    remote.Transact (IAdditionServiceStub.TransactionGetParcelableObj, __data, __reply, 0);
                    __reply.ReadException ();
                    __result = __reply.ReadInt () != 0 ? (global::Xamarin.AidlDemo.ParcelableObj) global::Android.OS.Bundle.Creator.CreateFromParcel (__reply) : null;

                } finally {
                    __reply.Recycle ();
                    __data.Recycle ();
                }
                return __result;

            }


        }

        internal const int TransactionAdd = global::Android.OS.Binder.InterfaceConsts.FirstCallTransaction + 0;

        internal const int TransactionGetParcelableObj = global::Android.OS.Binder.InterfaceConsts.FirstCallTransaction + 1;

        public abstract int Add (int value1, int value2);

        public abstract global::Xamarin.AidlDemo.ParcelableObj GetParcelableObj ();

    }
}
```

Let me know how to fix this De-marshalling error with parcellable objects between two apps or process in Xamarin Android

Comment: Your code does not contain the most important part — where is source code of `IAdditionServiceStub`? The root of problem most likely lies there.

Comment: as it was auto generated, i have't  included. now i have included the stub also. Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in Xamarin AIDL generator.

Note this line in IAdditionServiceStub (inside the nested class `Proxy`):

```
__result = __reply.ReadInt () != 0 ? (global::Xamarin.AidlDemo.ParcelableObj) global::Android.OS.Bundle.Creator.CreateFromParcel (__reply) : null;
```

It looks like total nonsense: the code is using `Android.OS.Bundle.Creator.CreateFromParcel` to decode IPC response as instance of `Bundle`, then tries to cast the result to `ParcelableObj`.

Your `ParcelableObj` is of course not an instance of `Bundle`. Event if it was, the code would still be incorrect — the only appropriate way to create a Parcelable class is by using `CREATOR` field of **that class**, e.g. `ParcelableObj.Creator.CreateFromParcel`. Create a Java project with same *.aidl file and try to compare the code generated by Google's *aidl* tool with IAdditionServiceStub you posted above, — you will see the issue yourself.

I am not sufficiently well-versed in C# to determine cause of the bug, but you should try upgrading your Xamarin installation. Maybe the bug was fixed already. If it wasn't, try to create an issue on Xamarin bugtracker (if there isn't one already).

In meantime, until the bug is resolved on Xamarin side, you have several options.

1. Remove generated AIDL interface, remove your *.aidl files, write IPC marshalling code by hand. Ough.
2. Use Messenger + Bundle as described in [this official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger). There will be a bit of boilerplate for each method, but this approach is usable overall.
3. Alternatively move the IPC code to separate Java library module. If you do so, you should be able to generate your IPC proxy implementation using official *aidl* tool or by other means (such using a [library](https://github.com/chdir/aidl2) I wrote myself for that purpose).

Comment: Thanks,  I will be trying the 2nd & 3rd options with xamarin case & hoping it should resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks.. the 2nd & 3rd suggestions worked. But I prefer to go with IPC with java AAR lib

Comment: Does anyone know if this bug in Xamarin has been fixed. Apparently I am having the same issue